# Перегруженная функция чистильщика

Tags: c++, visual-studio, указатели, память

Как исправить данную ошибку.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct A {};
struct B {};

void F(A*) {}
void F(B*) {}

int main()
{
    /* E0299 не удается определить экземпляр перегруженная функция "F",
       использование которого предполагается */
    std::shared_ptr<A> p{new A, F};

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделать 2 вещи:

Первое - объявить `void F(A*) {}`, ибо делетер работает с **указателем**.

Второе...

- Либо убрать перегрузку для `B`.
- Либо разрешить неопределенность самостоятельно - `std::shared_ptr<A> p(new A, (void (*)(A*))F);`
- Либо дописать переходник: `std::shared_ptr<A> p{new A, [](A* p){F(p);}};`

Comment: без каста не обойтись то есть? а через механизм шаблонов нельзя как то решить?

Comment: Ну, я пока не вижу способа, как заставить компилятор выполнить разрешение в данной ситуации...

Answer (score 1):

Если для удаления объектов класса должна использоваться специальная функция зачистки, то имеет смысл реализовать специализацию `std::default_delete` и не передавать дополнительных параметров в умные указатели. Этот вариант подходит, если тип удаляемого объекта полон (complete):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct A {};
struct B {};

void F(A*) {}
void F(B*) {}

namespace std
{

template<>
struct default_delete<::A>
{
    public: void
    operator ()(::A * p) const
    {
       cout << "spec deleter";
       ::F(p);
    }
};

} // namespace std

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<A> p{new A};
    return 0;
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FafkztPkyK3npCbW)